# How to apply conditional join in EF Core?

Tags: ef-core-2.1

Let's say I have a table `Contacts`, `Customers`, and `Suppliers`. **Contacts** has a column `ContactTypeId` and `ExternalContactId`. So you could end up with either:

```
var extContacts = from ct in _context.Contacts
                  join cu in _context.Customers
                  on ct.ExternalContactId equals cu.Id
```

Or I could have this as well

```
var extContacts = from ct in _context.Contacts
                  join su in _context.Suppliers
                  on ct.ExternalContactId equals su.Id
```

Here, I've showed only 2 joins to illustrate my point. In my case, I have 5 tables.

Is there any way, I can make just one call, join Contacts table depending on the `ContactTypeId`? Otherwise I may have to make more than 1 call (up to 5).

Something like:

```
var extContacts = from ct in _context.Contacts
                  join (
                         //if type is Customer --> Join with Customers table
                         //if type is supplier --> join with Suppliers table
                       )
                  select name, phone, address //fields common to both tables
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: What will be `select`-ed from the joined table(s)?

Comment: @IvanStoev please see the update.

Comment: Ok. I guess `ContactTypeId`  is some sort of enum indicating which entity/table `ExternalContactId` is referencing? Anyway, `Concat` query would have been the simplest. Unfortunately currently EF Core does not translate `Concat` / `Union` queries to SQL, so if you have 5 types, it would execute 5 SQL queries. Is that ok for you? If not, I can suggest query with multiple left outer joins and conditional selects for each property.

Comment: are u suggesting a stored procedure instead?